# How do I find the projection of a vector in three dimensions?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

Let  $\textbf r(t)=\langle\sin(t),\cos(t),9\sin(t)+5\cos(2t)\rangle$.

Find the projection of  $\textbf r(t)$  onto the  $xz$-plane for  $−1\le x\le1$.

I have no clue how to start.

[image]

Comment: The convenient thing about Cartesian coordinates is that the $x,z$ plane (for example) is simply all the points where $y=0,$ and you can project any point onto that plane just by changing the $y$ coordinate to zero. That's an orthogonal projection onto the $x,z$ plane. If you are supposed to use some other projection (not orthogonal), however, there will be a different formula depending on the projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $t \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
x = \sin(t)\\
z = 9 \sin(t) + 5 \cos(2t) 
$$
that means
$$
t=\sin^{-1}(x)
$$
and
$$
z(x) = 9 \sin(\sin^{-1}(x)) + 5 \cos(2\sin^{-1}(x)) \\
=  9 x + 5 \cos(2\sin^{-1}(x))
$$

Comment: doesn't work when i put that in

Comment: sorry but where are you putting that ? $x=\sin(t)$ means that $-1 \leq x \leq 1$

Comment: in my math homework

Comment: see my updated question, i inserted a picture

Comment: you had to say that you want $z$ as a function of $x$

Comment: my bad, how would that fix it

Comment: My really thank you very much.